# How to clear cache of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0

I'm working with eclipse and play framework with the command eclipsify, when I change a class , for example with a **System.out.println("blabla")** and run this as a java application there is no effect on the console, only when i try this one hour later the console print **blabla**. I think that this is a problem with the cache because it compiles fine when i do this with the command line of windows : java -cp ...

Comment: Tag your question with version of Play that you are using

Comment: could you provide some more info like what commands you use to "run this as a java application"

Comment: I create a class on the controllers package for example, then I press the right click over the code area and select run > as java application, like a standalone class with its main method.